# how to optimize inline images in ck-editor

Tags: 8, media, performance

Is it possible to optimize inline images uploaded via ck-editor.

There is an image with size 11 MB and in default behavior its rendered original without any optimization applied to it.

Comment: I think you're looking for this core issue, which unfortunately has been going on for a very long time: https://www.drupal.org/node/2061377

Comment: Im also trying to find how to optimize those images as well, there are tons of modules like resmush.it but they work with image styles which is useless in many cases, unfortunately there's no out of the box solution to this in 2020 neither.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in the image below, you only have these settings to optimize your image via upload in CKeditor. Using it you can for sure set the image dimensions, file size and path for images.

The below screenshot is from Drupal 8. You can get the same settings at www.example.com/admin/config/content/formats/manage/full_html

[image: Images optimization]